# Bottle server: HTTPResponse vs bottle.response

Tags: python, http, bottle

I have a bottle instance whose server is set to a multi-threaded http server with a threadpool.

We know one common way to for a bottle server to return from a route is

```
return HTTPResponse(status=200, body=json.dumps({'key':'value'})
```

I am also using an `after_request` hook, which tries to set some headers on the response by referring to `bottle.response`, and I found that inside the `after_request` hook code, it can no longer access that same `HTTPResponse` object, because whatever is referenced by `bottle.response` is a new response object. The object as returned by `HTTPResponse` is lost.

And my theory is that it's because `bottle.response` references `LocalResponse()`, and is therefore thread-local.

Assuming I cannot modify my after_request hook code, what can I do so that my after_request hook can still access the same `HTTPResponse` object?

I can think of 2 ways:

1) Instead of returning a new `HTTPResponse`, I just return a dictionary as the body:

`return json.dumps({'key','value'})`

But how can I return a status code other than 200 now?

2) Instead of returning a new `HTTPResponse`, do:

`bottle.response.status = 200; 
bottle.response.body = json.dumps({'key':'value'}); 
return bottle.response`

Is 2) thread-safe? Will it cause issues for multiple requests hitting the server and the returned responses get mixed up in the after_request hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using `bottle.response` is thread-safe, even in hooks.

NOTE: Personally, I prefer using Bottle's plugins instead of hooks - your plugin can receive the returned `HTTPResponse` object and act on it directly, which IMO is cleaner than relying on thread local "magic."